# I have a light dent in my wooden door, what is the best way to fix it?

Tags: repair, wood, doors

[image: Here is a picture of the light dent]

I had created this small dent in my door and I am wondering how to fix it.

Comment: What type of door is it; I mean from the inside? Like is it a solid wood (I doubt it is)? If it is just a wooden frame with a panel fixed on it you can put a foil specialized for this purpose. This will mask the dent, but generally speaking those doors are poor quality if it is an option for you maybe you should replace them.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a steam iron over a linen cloth it works on dents on solid wood. I appears on the picture your dent might be a break in the wood. Give the steam a try.